# Call and execute an r script from Python

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I am trying to use this Python script to call an r script and run it. The r script is dbc2csv.r, whose code is below the Python block.
I managed to call the r script and R studio opens but then the code does not run automatically as I would like it to happen. My feeling is that there is something wrong in the `subprocess.call` line but I can't figure out what.

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir("path")


def dbc2csv(raw_filename):
    dbc2csv_path = "Code\\R\\dbc2csv.R " + "Data\\CNES\\2005" + " " + "Data\\CNES\\2005"  + " " + raw_filename

    try:
        r_script_path = subprocess.getoutput('Code\\R\\dbc2csv.r')
        subprocess.call([r_script_path, "--vanilla", dbc2csv_path])
        return True
    except:
        print("dbc2csv - Error converting file: " + raw_filename)

        return False
 
dbc2csv("Data\\CNES\\STAC0508.dbc")
```

This is the r script I am trying to call and execute.

```
#install.packages("read.dbc") You need this package
library("read.dbc")


dbc2dbf <- function(rawDir, convertedDir, file) {
  # reads dbc file
  x <- read.dbc(paste(rawDir, file, sep=""))
  # write it to csv
  write.csv(x, file=paste(convertedDir, file, ".csv", sep=""))
}

args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
try(dbc2dbf(args[1], args[2], args[3]), TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Python .py scripts that can be automatically run at command line with `python.exe`, R scripts can be run with `Rscript.exe` (an executable in bin folder of R installation directory). This will run R code in background process without need of an IDE like RStudio. (Remember like any programming language you can write R code in simple text editor without any IDE).

Below uses [**`subprocess.Popen`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) which is more useful to capture output and error of child process and change working directory in child process. Plus, you pass args in a list instead of space separated string. Remember an error in child process will not raise a Python exception.

```
def dbc2csv(raw_filename):
   command = 'C:/Path/To/bin/Rscript.exe' 
   # command = 'Rscript'                    # OR WITH bin FOLDER IN PATH ENV VAR 
   arg = '--vanilla' 

   try: 
     p = subprocess.Popen([command, arg,
                          "Code/R/dbc2csv.R",
                          "Data/CNES/2005", 
                          "Data/CNES/2005",   
                          raw_filename],
                          cwd = os.getcwd(),
                          stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
                          stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                          stderr = subprocess.PIPE) 

     output, error = p.communicate() 

     if p.returncode == 0: 
        print('R OUTPUT:\n {0}'.format(output.decode("utf-8"))) 
     else: 
        print('R ERROR:\n {0}'.format(error.decode("utf-8"))) 

     return True

   except Exception as e: 
     print("dbc2csv - Error converting file: " + raw_filename) 
     print(e)

     return False
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not call the R script through Rstudio, but with *Rscript*. This is a command line program that comes with R and is provided for particular this purpose.

If you write the result to a CSV file, I would not hard code it into your R script, but pass the filename to the script as a command line parameter (can be obtained in the R script with *commandArgs*). Then you can store the file in a temporary directory, as e.g. created with the python module *tempfile*.

Comment: Not really helpful - if it runs in RStudio, why would it not run in RScript? Also OP is trying to run from Python and not from console!

Comment: @shtala: OP runs it through *subprocess*, which allows for stdin/stdout redirect. As the filenames apparently are on a Windows OS, you need a command line program for using anonymous pipes, which simply won't work with Rstudio. Moreover, the quetsion is about running an R scirpt NOT interactively but from Python, which is exactly the use case for Rscript.