# Execute R script in Python and get returning string variable

Tags: python, r, string, rscript

I have one R script that create a csv file and returned de filename string.

I need to execute that R script in Python and then use de returned string to upload that file.
My R scripts is create_file.r and has 3 args date_from, date_to, client. How can I execute that script in python?
And then how can I use the returned string var filename???

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call and execute an r script from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716500/call-and-execute-an-r-script-from-python)

Comment: I see that, but I don`t know how to get the execution result in that post